# debugging error: Licenses.licx : unable to resolve type

Tags: winforms, licensing, componentone, licenses.licx, emptylicenseslicx

I am using a ComponentOne FlexGrid, it automatically registered in its license

> C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.C1FlexGrid, C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.2,
>   Version=2.6.20122.716, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=79882d576c6336da

I also use a custom control that inherits the C1FlexGrid, but on run-time it tries to register

> DataTree.C1FlexDataTree, fpstudio, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null

in the license file, which ultimately creates an error:

> Error 51  Unable to resolve type 'DataTree.C1FlexDataTree, fpstudio,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'  C:_DEVELOPMENT_FP_DRAFT12\COMPONENT1_WORKING_MERGED\fpstudio\Properties\licenses.licx 3   Freepour
>   Studio

How can I tell this class not to try to license the control as it already is inherited and is licensed itself. I have already removed `[LicenseProvider()]` from the DataTree Class

Comment: I don't know if this will end up helping you, but whenever we have ComponentOne issues with licensing, we just create a blank form, add the proper components, then rebuild the application. ComponentOne will then properly add the licenses to the file. Alternatively, are you sure you're referencing the right version? Have you tried "Specific Version" = false on the reference?

Comment: Do you have the property Compile operation set to 'Embedded Resource' for the licenses.licx?

Comment: `Build Action: Embedded Resource` is what I have.  I think @notacat's answer is correct.  You can't prevent it, but you can just edit the licenses.licx file to remove the offending entry (in my case, the class I created that extends the licensed third party component.)  It will later be added any time I edit a form that uses that component, but it can be re-removed.  Annoying, but simple enough.

Answer (score 11):

This is a pain... I'd suggest you install the [EmptyLicensesLicx](https://github.com/caioproiete/EmptyLicensesLicx) nuget package, and it will make sure there's an empty `Licenses.licx` in your project, before it gets compiled (which is all you need).

Comment: I wish I had have found this package so long ago

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to do it is to edit licenses.licx file manually and remove DataTree.C1FlexDataTree from there. Note, VS edits licenses.licx file automatically when you work with forms and controls in designer. If you close all designer windows and edit licx file manually, your changes will be saved and you can avoid issues. 
The most common issue with licx files is build error after you updated controls to other version. To avoid it, you can just remove version and public key token information from this file at all. After that it would work with any version. I.e. you licenses.licx file content should look like this:

```
C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.C1FlexGrid, C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.2
DataTree.C1FlexDataTree, fpstudio
```

(or without DataTree.C1FlexDataTree line).
Note, if you open designer to do some changes, VS can edit this file again. There is no way to prevent that. You'll have to edit file once more time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solutions was to open a new blank form in the project, add to that form every object that comes with your library.
Then perform a "Build" and Visual Studio updates your .licx file with the correct info on the added objects, overwriting any old date held in that file.
All "non-resolved" types associated with your file will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was pretty simple, just open the file licenses.licx, empty the content, save the changes and run your solution again. Note: Don't delete the file, just empty the content.

Hope this works for you.